# Symfony2: how to allow entity field to accept new data

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I am new to Symfony and got stuck on custom form fields.
I have following field with "entity type" which works fine. It allows me to type in text box, showing matched results and when not match, showing "No Match Found".
What I want is, if there is no match, want to show "Add New" option in same select box and I will type new option which will save after form binds.

Here is my entity field type code

```
    $builder->add('companies', 'entity', array(
        'class'     => 'MyBundle:Company',
        'multiple'  => true,
        'expanded'  => false,
        'label'     => 'Companies',
        'empty_value' => false,
        'attr'      => array(
            'style' => 'width:400px'
        ),
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($account) {
            //query here
        }
    ));
```

How do I implement this, so if no option matched, it will ask me to add new and then I can same new option there.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to create a custom form field type.
documentation for custom types can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Maybe you could find a third party bundle doing this.